# How to load sliding drawer from left to right?

Tags: android, sliding, drawer

I am working with android.I had searched a lot to create a sliding drawer from left to right.But most of the tutorials gives from top to bottom . How can I create a sliding drawer from left to right ?? please help me I am new in android ,thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually when you create a new Activity from

`File -> New -> Other -> Android -> Android Activity`
You can choose in the second page the Navigation Type, if you choose Navigation Drawer your activity comes equipped with a navigation drawer that you can pull from the left.

There are a lot of comments to explain how the drawer works in the newly created activity, and you can customize it to your liking.